# Rewriting expression in terms of factor

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have two expressions:

```
expr = (a - R)^2 (a + 2 R)/(2 R^3);
factor = 1 - a^2/R^2;
```

I would like to write `expr` in terms of `factor` -- is there a function in *Mathematica* to help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite your definitions as equations (i.e. using `==`), then use `Solve` to solve for `expr` specifying that the `R` and `a` variables should be eliminated:

```
Clear[expr, factor]

Solve[
  {expr == (a - R)^2 (a + 2 R)/(2 R^3), factor == 1 - a^2/R^2},
  expr,
  {R, a}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html)

```
Eliminate[{expr == e, factor == f}, {a, R}]
```

> ```
> 3 f^2 + f^3 == (8 - 4 e) e
> ```

Comment: Alternatively: `GroebnerBasis[{expr == (a - R)^2 (a + 2 R)/(2 R^3), factor == 1 - a^2/R^2}, {expr, factor}, {a, R}]`.