# Express in terms of a new variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a simple expression:

```
s=4a(x+y)^3
```

I want to express s in terms of b where b=x+y. That is s will become 4ab^3. How to achieve this in Mathematica?

Comment: `Eliminate[{s == 4 a (x + y)^3, b == x + y}, {x, y}]` or `Reduce[{s == 4 a (x + y)^3, b == x + y}, {b, s}, {x, y}]`

Comment: `s = 4 a (x + y)^3 /. (x + y) -> b`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions)

Answer (score 2):

Already mentioned in the comments(nothing new) by @corey979 and @Artes.

```
In[49]:= Clear[s, b]

Solve[{s == 4 a (x + y)^3, b == x + y}, s, {x, y}]

Out[50]= {{s -> 4 a b^3}}
```

Ref: [Rewriting expression in terms of factor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108328/rewriting-expression-in-terms-of-factor), Thanks to MarcoB